undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type while trying to load a .so file in .net core 8.0
I am trying to load a .so file using DllImport. The .so file is created from a .py file using cython.
While execution it gives a symbol lookup error : undefined symbol.
Error message : Unable to load shared library 'test.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable:
/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.3/test.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type
I have read multiple posts facing the same error while trying to load .so file.
Few of them suggested setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Python is installed on the machine at location : /usr/bin/python3. So I have also tries setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /usr/bin and /usr/bin/python3.
Both of which gave me the same error.
My assumption : I believe this is a dependency issue. The .so file is being loaded. But while execution it is not getting necessary libraries to execute.
Python 3.10.12
.Net core 8.0
Please help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
